# Optimize query mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i have a problem with a  query for a web site. This is the situation:
I have 3 table:
**articoli** = where there are all article
**clasart** = where there are all the matches between the code article and class code - 32314 rows
**classificazioni** = where there are all matches between class code and name of class - 2401 rows

and this is the query

```
SELECT a.clar_classi , b.CLA_DESCRI 
FROM clasart a JOIN (
SELECT art.AI_CAPOCODI, art.ai_codirest 
FROM (select * from clasart where clar_azienda = 'SRL') a 
JOIN (
    SELECT AI_CAPOCODI, AI_CODIREST,AI_DT_CREAZ, 
        AI_DESCRIZI, AI_CATEMERC, concat(AI_CAPOCODI, AI_CODIREST) as codice, aI_grupscon 
    FROM articoli 
    WHERE AI_AZIENDA = 'SRL' AND AI_CATEMERC LIKE '0101______' AND AI_FLAG_NOW = 0 AND AI_CAPOCODI <> 'zzz' 
) art ON trim(a.CLAR_ARTICO) = art.AI_CODIREST 
JOIN classificazioni b ON a.CLAR_CLASSI = b.CLA_CODICE 
WHERE b.CLA_CODICE LIKE 'AA51__' 
group by CLAR_ARTICO) art ON trim(CLAR_ARTICO) = concat(art.AI_CAPOCODI, art.ai_codirest) 
JOIN classificazioni b ON a.CLAR_CLASSI = b.CLA_CODICE 
WHERE CLAR_AZIENDA = 'SRL' AND CLAR_CLASSI like 'CO____'
```

The time of run is 16 second. The time increase to 16 second when join with classificazioni.

You can help me? Thanks

Comment: First of all, change all the `AI_CATEMERC LIKE '0101______'` to `AI_CATEMERC = '0101______'`. You do not use wildcards in your `LIKE` so it's unnecessary.

Comment: if i change like in = not found result

Comment: Rewrite the query getting rid of subqueries.  These hinder the optimizer and they are not necessary.

Comment: @lolka_bolka FYI the underscore character *is* a wildcard for "any single character". It's standard SQL.

Comment: @Bohemian Thx, I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce following indexing using the queries below and after that the query will start running within a second or two:

`ALTER TABLE articoli ADD INDEX idx_artc_az_cat_flg_cap (AI_AZIENDA, AI_FLAG_NOW, AI_CAPOCODI, AI_CATEMERC);`

The above query will introduce the multi-column indexes on articoli table. The indexing work similar way how hash tables or keys of the array work to directly identifying the row on which the target value(s) match. Using multi-column will result in comparison of less number of rows.

Do not use `trim(a.CLAR_ARTICO)`: make sure that before insertion the values are trimmed but not at the time of joining. This can result in skipping the index files and the join comparison can be expensive this way.

Let's move to next steps:

Introduce index on `clar_azienda` using following query:

`ALTER TABLE clasart ADD INDEX idx_cls_az (clar_azienda);`

If art.AI_CODIREST is not a primary/foreign key you'll need to introduce index there using the query below:

`ALTER TABLE classificazioni ADD INDEX idx_clsi_cd (CLA_CODICE);`

We are almost done, you'll just need to index `CLAR_AZIENDA` as well the same way how I indexed the above columns. Let me also tell you what is what in index column last query so you can write your own.

`ALTER TABLE <tableName> ADD INDEX <indexKey (<column to be indexed>);`

Let me know if you still have issues, remember you can run these queries after selecting your database from PhpMyAdmin (SQL tabl) or on mysql console.